# Looping over vectors (NOT looping over elements in a vector)

Tags: r, loops, vector

I currently have, say, 2 vectors

```
x <- 1:2
y <- 3:4
```

I am looking to do something like

```
for (i in c("x","y"))
{
  i <- data.frame(i)
  i$flag <- ifelse(i == "x", 1, 0)  # just a flagging field
}
```

I am obviously referring to x and y incorrectly. However, I am unsure as to how else to do so.

Comment: what are you trying to do? What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is part of a simulation exercise. The vectors are a performance measurement each of a distinct population. They have been each been sampled from their corresponding empirical data.

The loop above is to label each population before rbinding them to calculate differences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Map` and pass `x` and `y` as `list` argument and characters `"x"` and `"y"` as another argument. This will give you list of two separate dataframes

```
Map(function(x, y) data.frame(x, y = as.integer(y == "x")), list(x, y), c("x", "y"))

#[[1]]
#  x y
#1 1 1
#2 2 1

#[[2]]
#  x y
#1 3 0
#2 4 0
```

---

Or Maybe only with `lapply`

```
lst <- list(x = x, y = y)
lapply(seq_along(lst), function(x) 
       data.frame(x = lst[[x]], y = as.integer(names(lst)[x] == "x")))
```

Comment: The Map method is the neater. I really like it. Thank you. Though lapply is perhaps the easier to understand which has the advantage when it comes to re-readability (e.g. months later).

I noticed you didn't opt for a for loop method. Is it a good practice to use apply/map functions if possible?

Comment: @T.Fung Usually in R, very rarely you'll require an explicit `for` loop. Most of the times `apply` family of functions are enough to do what you need and yes it is a good practice to use them.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly and you want to loop over entire vectors instead of vector elements, you can put your vectors into a list and then loop over the list.

Like so:

```
x <- c(1:10)
y <- c(11:20)

for (item in list(x, y)) {
    # your code
}
```

Edit (after your clarification):

If you want to turn both vectors into data.frames this is equally simple. First, put both vectors into a list, then modify them in your loop:

```
x <- c(1:10)
y <- c(11:20)
list_of_vectors <- list(x, y)

for (i in seq_along(list_of_vectors)) {
    list_of_vectors[[i]] <- as.data.frame(list_of_vectors[[i]])
}
```

However a more R-ish solution would be to use the `lapply`:

```
x <- c(1:10)
y <- c(11:20)
list_of_vectors <- list(x, y)
list_of_vectors <- lapply(list_of_vectors, as.data.frame)
```

Comment: Thank you @moonpainter I am looking to turn both vectors x and y into 2 separate dataframes. After this loop, the 2 vectors remain as vectors

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I edited the answer now to reflect your clarification. However this is very similar to the other answer.

Comment: So the moral of the story (judging from kind help from Ronak and yourself) if I needed to loop or apply over vectors, first put them in a list and refer to them with [[]]

Thank you too @moonpainter